# Can one http request call multiple css files?

Tags: html, css, performance, httprequest

Is it possible to add multiple css in header tag with one http request to execute all css file at once ?

I know about

```
@import url('/css/typography.css');
@import url('/css/layout.css');
@import url('/css/color.css');
```

can we do something like or any other solution to reduce `http requests`

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/typography.css,layout.css,color.css'>
```

Comment: If minimizing http request is really necessary for you, then try merging the css files (if they are related and and it is possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bundle your CSS files for production and minify ofc.

http://www.sitepoint.com/faster-page-loads-bundle-your-css-and-javascript/

Comment: yes this page i am looking for same 
http://www.sitepoint.com/faster-page-loads-bundle-your-css-and-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

No but you can club all your style sheets into one sheet and import that like so:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/main.css'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use ASP.NET MVC bundling and minification feature. 
You create a bundle like this:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/customcss").Include(
      "~/Content/css/typography.css",
      "~/Content/css/layout.css",
      "~/Content/css/color.css"));
```

And you can render it like this (in a Razor View):

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/customcss")
```

In Release compilation mode, your bundles will be automatically merged and minified, but you can set the flag manually in Debug mode as well:

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

See [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can? with apache/nginx MODPAGESPEED https://www.modpagespeed.com/

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/yellow.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/blue.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/big.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/bold.css">
</head>
```

can become

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/yellow.css+blue.css+big.css+bold.css.pagespeed.cc.xo4He3_gYf.css">
</head>
```

Disclaimer: Apache PageSpeed is an effort undergoing incubation at The Apache Software Foundation (ASF), sponsored by the Apache Incubator.